# How compiling GTK+ static on mac os x

Tags: c, macos, gtk

I have working program in GTK+
It compiling good on Linux and in Mac OS X (brew)

How compiling it in mac with static option?

on mac:

$ pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0

-D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+/2.24.30/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+/2.24.30/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.38.1/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/harfbuzz/1.2.1/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.38.1/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/atk/2.18.0_1/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.14.6_1/include/cairo -I/usr/local/Cellar/pixman/0.34.0/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/fontconfig/2.11.1_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.6.3/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.21/include/libpng16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdk-pixbuf/2.32.3/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.21/include/libpng16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.46.2/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.46.2/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+/2.24.30/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.38.1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/atk/2.18.0_1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.14.6_1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/gdk-pixbuf/2.32.3/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.46.2/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -lgtk-quartz-2.0 -lgdk-quartz-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl

on mac is clang llvm not gcc

When I use -static option I get:

$ gcc -Wall -static -o prog prog.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0`

```
ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: *How* are you building? Can you please show the complete command lines with all options (all source/object files not needed, placeholders are okay)?

Comment: on every system gcc -Wall  -o prog prog.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0`

Comment: GTK+ does not officially support static linking. If you want to statically link GTK+, you will need to build it (and all its dependencies) from scratch as static libraries.

Comment: @andlabs can You write me how?